# Changing format of Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following output with the groupby demand

```
created_at  sentiment
2021-04-19  NEGATIVE      20
            POSITIVE       7
2021-04-20  NEGATIVE     104
            POSITIVE      70
2021-04-21  NEGATIVE      64
            POSITIVE      53
2021-04-22  NEGATIVE     115
            POSITIVE      50
```

I want to get a new dataframe with the columns

```
'created_at', 'positive', 'negative',
2021-04-19     7           20       
2021-04-20     70          104

and so on.
```

I am thankful for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wanting to `pivot_table()`:

```
output = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='created_at',columns='sentiment',values='name_of_the_series')
```